# How do I add a bottom bar (NOT bottomTabs) with custom buttons for stack navigation in React Native Navigation (wix) v2?

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using RNN2 (React Native Navigation) by Wix v2 and I cannot find any references to have a simple bottom bar to add some custom buttons.

Here is my navigation set up, using bottomTabs (because I assume I can customize a bottom tab).

```
            bottomTabs: {
                children: [
                    {
                        stack: {
                            id: 'tab0',
                            children: [
                                {
                                    component: {
                                        id: FIRST_SCREEN,
                                        name: FIRST_SCREEN,
                                        options: {
                                            topBar: {
                                                title: {
                                                    text: 'Top Bar',
                                                },
                                            },
                                            bottomTab: {
                                                title: 'Tab 1',
                                                icon: require('./assets/topBar_logo.png'),
                                            },
                                        },
                                    },
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
```